# Apt-get is not installing jdk properly

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, java

Any time I try use apt-get install (I'm logged into the root account) It doesnt work properly this is what it comes up with (This is after trying to use it to install java jdk)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre is already the newest version.
openjdk-7-jre set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnfc-dev libnfc5 libpcsc-perl libsensors4-dev libsnmp-dev libsnmp-perl
  libsnmp-session-perl libssl-dev libwrap0-dev linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic linux-signed-image-3.16.0-41-generic
  pcsc-tools python-imaging-tk python-pyscard zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: what exactly is not working about it?

Comment: It looks a lot like it's already installed, and the latest version.

Comment: You could run `sudo apt-get autoremove` once as suggested by the output to get rid of that bunch of unneeded packages.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `jdk` not `jre`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @Oli in his question he's trying to use jdk, and installed jre by accident

Comment: Oh yeah, almost missed that.